# sizeof use on pointer variables not working

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

Why is this correct

```
int *block = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); 
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]);  //block_size = 2; correct
```

But this fails?

```
int **block = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); 
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]); // block_size = 1; incorrect
```

By the way, I thought I couldn't use [sizeof accurately on pointer variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)? How come it works for the first one?

Comment: You can use sizeof accurately. It accurately returns the size of a pointer. The trick you are trying to use only works for arrays. And note that it's just that - a trick that only works for arrays. It's not a magic way to see the size of what something is pointing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one only works by accident. Change that `2` to a `3` and watch what happens.

```
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]);  //block_size = 2
```

Since `block` is an `int *` and `block[0]` is an `int`, this gives the ratio of the size of a *pointer to an integer* to the size of an *integer*. This happens to be two on your platform. I'd guess your integers are 32-bits and your pointers are 64-bits.

```
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]); // block_size = 1
```

Since `block` is now an `int**`, this gives the ratio of the size of a *pointer to a pointer to an integer* to the size of a *pointer to an integer*. Likely on your platform all pointers are the same size.

If you want to know the size of a block you allocated, you have to keep track of it. The `sizeof` operator doesn't do what you think it does -- it tells you the sizes of *types*, not blocks of memory.

Comment: `all pointers are the same size.` - Not true. The standard does not guarantee that pointers to different types are the same size.

Comment: Before your edit you said "all pointers are the same size." That's a guarantee if I've ever heard one.  I'm not saying that you're often wrong in practice, just a nitpick. I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not right. None of it should work, and none is actually working here.

```
sizeof(block) != sizeof(block[0])+ sizeof(block[1])
```

So, to assume

```
block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]); = 2
```

is wrong!

`int*`/`void*`/`char*` are all just variables to hold addresses, they all 'mostly' are of same size.

And a `pointer` points to a block of memory which could be any no of bytes, doesn't depend upon the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pointers are 8 bytes size and int is 4 bytes:
lets look at :

```
int *block = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); 
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]);
```

1. block has been allocated 2*4 = 8 bytes of memory
2. sizeof(block) should return 8 because it is size of pointer (this will be same for int*,    char*,void* etc)
3. sizeof(block[0]) which is size of first element pointed by block should return 4
   so you have 8/4 = 2

next lets see :

```
int **block = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); 
size_t block_size = sizeof(block) / sizeof(block[0]); // block_size = 1; incorrect
```

1. block is pointer to pointer to int(double pointer)
2. block will be holding address(i.e., pointer to int), so sizeof(block) should return 8 and  sizeof(block[0]) which is again holding address should return 8. Note that: *block[0] is element and block[0] is address
3. so sizeof(block)/size[0] is 8/8 = 1

Hope this will help you